# How do to wc command in if statement

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, wc

There are other similar questions online out there, but I just couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code after trying those online suggestions. Below is my code:

```
LineNum = `wc -l <     /data/${INPUT:0:4}/${INPUT:4:2}/positions.$INPUT`
if [2 -le "$LineNum"] 
then
    echo ""
else
    awk 'NR!=1 {print $0}'     /data/${INPUT:0:4}/${INPUT:4:2}/positions.$INPUT | column -t
fi
```

So the $INPUT is in the format of YYYYMMDD, and I want the file to be displayed if the row count is more then a specific number. But I keep getting the error message "Command Not Found" for the if test.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated!

Comment: Don't put spaces around assignments!  (``LineNum = `wc -l < file` `` is wrong; ``LineNum=$(wc -l <file)`` would be better (or use backquotes, but `$(…)` is better than using backquotes).

Comment: `[` is a **command**; it's not syntax; it has no special handling by the shell parser at all. Just as you don't use `ls*.txt` to mean `ls *.txt`, you can't use `[2` to mean `[ 2`.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have found all these bugs for you automatically, instead of needing to involve humans. :)

Comment: Jonathan & Charles, thanks so much for the clear answer!!  I'm new to this, and these small things really drive me nuts

Comment: Charles thanks for the website, this would help me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing spaces around your condition. Try `if [ 2 -le "$LineNum" ]`.

Comment: Since this is tagged bash, one could also use `if (( 2 <= LineNum ))`.